# Accurate calculation for scaling all children of root (general parent) element

Tags: c#, html, c++, c, resize

.

.

.

.

.
Annotation for c/c++/c# members: Dont attention for html, look calculation example!
.

.

.

.

.

Im have big div - #wrapper. This wrapper resize on js by step 100px for fit where user resize window.

Wrapper have some children (boxes), and boxes (and children of boxes) have self dimensions (width, height, margins, paddings) in pixels.

I need accurate calculate proportions for all values.

Yes, i known scale() in CSS. But this have some bugs in Chromium for overflow (not hidden overflow content), and more - i need support IE 7/8

I have named problem - "one pixel problem". Look example:

```
<div class="#wrapper" style="width: 800px; height: 800px;">
<div class="box" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;">
    <div class="inner-box" style="width: 90px; height: 90px; margin: 5px 0 0 5px;"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Suppose wrapper decreased to size 500x500.

Calculation (pseudo language):

```
maxWrapperSize  = 800;
currWrapperSize = 500;
diff = currWrapperSize / maxWrapperSize; // 0.625

boxWidth  = 100 * diff; // 62.5
boxHeight = 100 * diff; // 62.5

innerBoxWidth  = 90 * diff; // 56.25
innerBoxHeight = 90 * diff; // 56.25
innerBoxMarginTop  = 5 * diff; // 3.125
innerBoxMarginLeft = 5 * diff; // 3.125

checkHeight = innerBoxMarginTop * 2 + innerBoxHeight; // 62.5 Yes!
```

But i need round without float. This is pixel MFG! You can show me half of pixel? Ok:

```
boxWidth  = round(boxWidth); // 63
boxHeight = round(boxHeight); // 63

innerBoxWidth  = round(innerBoxWidth); // 56
innerBoxHeight = round(innerBoxHeight); // 56
innerBoxMarginTop  = round(innerBoxMarginTop); // 3
innerBoxMarginLeft = round(innerBoxMarginLeft ); // 3

checkHeight = innerBoxMarginTop * 2 + innerBoxHeight; // 62 No!
```

So, my question: Howto accurate calculate this values?

Comment: why are you rounding the values then?

Comment: Need rounding for IE

Comment: Your explanation is not clear to me. but if you need to round those values then re-calculate the parent width. that should be `boxWidth X 8` => `63 X 8 = 504` instead of 500.

Comment: @Mr_Green boxes have more and more inner children, my example this very simple and not show full env.

Comment: Can you assign values in percentage using? that should work.. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3strsduk/). Use this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/3strsduk/show/) to see in IE7/IE8.

Comment: @Mr_Green yes, some elements have dimensions in percents. But other elements require set pixels. My question only for this "strange" elements.

Comment: Try using `*{box-sizing: border-box;}` in CSS..

Comment: @Mr_Green this is not support in IE7. Maybe calculate with checking even/odd values?

Comment: Why [c] [c++] and [c#] tags?

Comment: @kleszcz Im hope for exists solution in c/c++/c#